# Uploading to ArcGIS Online using the Cache toolset

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-online, cache

I am using the following steps in ArcMap:

1. Generate Tiling Scheme tool
2. Manage tiling scheme tool
3. Export Tile tool

in order to create a tile package for upload to ArcGIS Online.

I know my map document is more than 200MB( a large dataset), however, only 4MB is uploaded to ArcGIS Online.  I always realize the file is 4MB after I use the Manage tool.

Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

Comment: Try this approach, it gives option to share tile package to AGO.  Thats how I usually do them. http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-arcmap/how-to-create-a-tile-package.htm

Comment: When you are cooking your cache, the level of details your are cooking will impact the size, along with the format etc. Also using the share package tool as Simon mentioned is an excellent tool to upload large packages.

Comment: @Simon That looks worth expanding a fraction into an answer

Comment: @RussRoberts That looks worth posting as an answer

Answer (score 1):

From ArcMap:

1. Customize menu --> ArcMap Options --> Sharing tab
2. Under the Packaging section, tick the ‘Enable ArcGIS Runtime Tools’

[image]

3. File Menu --> Share As --> Tile Package.

[image]

You can choose to directly push it to your ArcGIS Online account (would need to be signed in first) from ArcMap, or you can create it as a file and then upload it via ArcGIS Online --> My Content.

[image]

However, if you expect the tile package to be over 256mb, recommend creating locally and then using the **Share Package** Tool under Data Management Toolbox.

[image]

Once uploaded, you then need to publish - this unpacks the tiles into a tiled map service (a new item) and voila.

[image]

You can check the status of the unpacking/publishing from the item page for the new tiled map service.

[image]

This is a handy way to bypass using up credits for creating caches, but remember you also use credits for storage of tiles, therefore worth deleting the original tile package item, as you no longer need this.